# Commands to search for YouTube videos via the search bar

Tags: youtube, search

If I enter `title:"This Hard Land" -title:"Cover"` in the YouTube search bar, I only get videos which contain *This Hard Land* and do not contain *Cover* in their titles.
I'd also like to add a command which forces the videos to appear ordered (for example by count view), probably something like `orderByCountView:`.

I don't want to achieve this by manipulating the URL or by using the advanced search options.

Does such command exist? Does anyone have a reference to an (official) list of all commands which one can uses in the search bar?

Comment: Generally speaking, Google _seldom_ offers any way to sort their search results. At best, they might offer a way to filter by view count, but it would still be ordered the way the algorithm thinks best.

Answer (score 2):

It seems not possible to do what you want. The blog cited in [the other answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28948/19350) states search commands that don't work today (e.g., `Apple, this week` returns videos from 3 years ago).

There is an [API reference](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_video_feeds) showing how you could do it with GET, and there's an [advanced search](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=111997) that also modifies the URL.

It's possible to do *what* you want, but not *how* you want to do it.

Comment: do you need developer key to try the API call. I was not able to do a search via the API (order by viewed count). Can you post a working API call to demo the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

All I could find was [this](http://web.archive.org/web/20150610013334/http://www.techstalks.com/advanced-youtube-search-with-simple-commands/), but it does not answer your question. Google does provide commands reference for GoogleSearch, but not for YouTube, and, after trying many things that came to my mind, the only answer I can think of is that there is no such a command.

Comment: The link is broken.

Comment: @Rubén http://web.archive.org/web/20150610013334/http://www.techstalks.com/advanced-youtube-search-with-simple-commands/

Answer (score -2):

This is possible with a feature Google build into its search. If you want to search for results from a specific page (in this case youtube.com) just type in site:youtube.com followed by the search terms you want. For example, if you're looking up "How to tie a tie" and you only want YouTube videos, just type this into the google search bar:

`site:youtube.com how to tie a tie`

Hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: That’s not what the OP asked. The OP asked for _YouTube_ search parameters.