# Is there a way to exclude YouTube videos from specific band?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist, youtube-watch-later

I'm wondering is there a way to filter YouTube videos from the band that I don't want to see?

I know how to exclude channel, YouTube is giving option for that, but is there a way to exclude whole music from one band on YouTube?

Comment: This question doesn't show any research effort. See [ask] for further details.

Comment: So, you think that I'll put up bounty without a research? I didn't find anything, that's why I put up bounty. Thanks for vote down.

Comment: The "problem" is that the question don't say what do you tried to find the answer or if you find a similar question it don't say why that question was not helpful.

Comment: Related: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/28846/commands-to-search-for-youtube-videos-via-the-search-ba

Answer (score -1):

## Short answer

Try Google ([google-search](/questions/tagged/google-search))

## Explanation

Youtube offers basic and advanced search; the official documentation doesn't include search operators that regular users could use, only an article pointed to Youtube creators but Google has more options for searching and filtering results and both services are from the same company.

You could use `site:youtube.com` to limit results to Youtube and the `-` operator to exclude any search term, like the name of a band.

## References

### Youtube help center

- [Filters (Advanced search)](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/111997?hl=en)
- [Use advanced search in video manager](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2685977?hl=en)

### Google Search help center

- [Search operators](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2466433?hl=en)
- [Filter your search results](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/142143?hl=en)

Comment: You could basically link me www.google.com and tell me to search for the answer. I asked the question, didn't find anything, I'm asking here, you're basically telling me to google it myself.

Comment: @JosipIvic: I'm sorry that you take this answer in the wrong way. As [ask] suggest, please keep an open mind: *The answer to your question may not always be the one you wanted, but that doesn’t mean it is wrong. A conclusive answer isn’t always possible. When in doubt, ask people to cite their sources, or to explain how/where they learned something. Even if we don’t agree with you, or tell you exactly what you wanted to hear, remember: we’re just trying to help.*

Comment: I'm not a new user Ruben.